# $http.get call app.get in Express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Code in server.js

```
var strava = require('node-strava-v3')
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    strava.streams.activity({'id': 497191235, 'types':'distance'}, function(err, payload){
        if(!err){
            res.send(payload);
        }
        else{
            res.send(err);
        }
    })
});
```

I would like to setup a view file (static HTML with a dynamic view) which gets its data via a controller file, which in turn retrieves it from the model (server.js) through `app.get()` call. I believe I would need to utilise `$http.get()` from the controller to access `app.get()`? The tutorials I read have provided a specifc path as the argument for `$http.get()`, but I don't think it applies to my situation.

Please advise - thank you.

[Edit] controller.js and index.html files at present:

//controller.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',

function($scope, $http){    
    var refresh = function(){
        $http.get('/').success(function(response){ 
        $scope.contactlist = response;
        });
    };  

    refresh();
}]);
```

//index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Contact List App</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <p>{{contactlist}}</p>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just do something like `$http.get('/')`?

Comment: Hi Ashley, I have tried that approach. The content that gets spitted out is the HTML code (i.e. it shows up as the HTML code as the content when localhost:3000 is accessed).